# How to place the captcha just below the comments text area

Tags: customization

Hi I am new to word press. I have downloaded  bot detect captcha. It is working finely. The only problem is that the captcha appears above the comments text area. I need it to appaear just below the comments text area and just above the post comment button.How can I do it?? Please help me..

Comment: Where can we see the source code of the plugin?

Comment: I am using zeesynergie theme. I just downloaded bot detect captcha plugin and activated it.

Comment: Add a link to the source code.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/botdetect-wp-captcha/